# How to determine $x, y, z$ coordinates of the third vertex of a 3D triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d, computational-geometry

Given a line $AB$ such that $A(0,0,0)$ and $B(4,7,9)$. How can I obtain a point $C(x,y,z)$ of $\Delta ABC$ with $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$ known?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given two fixed points  $A$ and $B$ in three space and two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ which together with $c=|AB|$ satisfy the triangle inequalities. We are looking for a point $C$ such that $|AB| = c, \,\, |BC|=a$ and $|CA| = b$.

Assume we have found one such point $C$. Let $H \in AB$ be the (unique) point on $AB$ such that $CH$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Since we are in three space, it turns out that all points $C$ that satisfy the conditions $|BC|=a$ and $|CA| = b$ form a circle lying on the plane through $H$ perpendicular to line $AB$. Moreover, the center of the circle is $H$ and its radius is $|CH|$. WE want to find a parametrization of that circle.

As already mentioned, point $H \in AB$ is such that $CH$ is perpendicular to $AB$, i.e. $CH$ is the altitude of triangle $ABC$ through the vertex $C$. Then $H$ splits the segment $AB$ into two segments $AH$ and $BH$. Let $|AH| = c_b$ and $|BH| = c_a$. By construction $c_a+c_b = c.$ Furthermore, by Pythagoras' theorem $$b^2 - c_b^2 = |CH|^2 = a^2-c_a^2.$$ Thus, we have a system of 2 equations for the unknown variables $c_a,c_b$:

\begin{align}
c_b^2-c_a^2 &= b^2-a^2\\
c_b+c_a &= c
\end{align} 
and when we solve it we obtain 
\begin{align}
c_b &= \frac{b^2-a^2+c^2}{2c}\\
c_a &= \frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2c}
\end{align}
Furthermore, we can find the length of the altitude
$$|CH| = \sqrt{b^2-c_b^2} = \frac{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}}{2c}$$

Next, observe that the coordinate system is with origin $A$. Let $\overrightarrow{e}_1 = (1,0,0)$. Then clearly $\overrightarrow{e}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{AB}$ are linearly independent. Therefore vector $\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}$ is perpendicular to vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and vector $\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)$ is perpendicular to both vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$  and $\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}$. Furthermore, the vectors $$\frac{\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}}{|\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}|} \,\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\, \frac{\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)}{|\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)|}$$ are of unit length and are perpendicular to each other, as well as each of them is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{AB}$. Therefore, the circle we are looking for can be parametrized as
$$\overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{AH} + |CH| \left(\cos{\theta} \, \frac{\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)}{|\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)|} + \sin{\theta} \, \frac{\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}}{|\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}|}\right).$$ But $$\overrightarrow{AH} = c_b\frac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{|AB|} = \frac{c_b}{c}\overrightarrow{AB}.$$ Thus
$$\overrightarrow{AC} = \frac{c_b}{c}\overrightarrow{AB} + \sqrt{c^2-c_b^2} \left(\cos{\theta} \, \frac{\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)}{|\overrightarrow{AB} \times(\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{e}_1)|} + \sin{\theta} \, \frac{\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}}{|\overrightarrow{e}_1 \times \overrightarrow{AB}|}\right).$$ We know everything in this equation -- we have vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{e_1}$, as well as 
\begin{align}
c_b &= \frac{b^2-a^2+c^2}{2c}\\
\sqrt{b^2-c_b^2} &= \frac{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}}{2c}.
\end{align}
My brief computations show that in numbers
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1\\ C_2 \\ C_3
\end{pmatrix} =  \frac{c_b}{c}\begin{pmatrix}
4\\  7\\ 9 
\end{pmatrix}  + \sqrt{c^2-c_b^2} \left(\frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sqrt{4749}}  \, \begin{pmatrix}
-65\\  14\\ 18 
\end{pmatrix}  + \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{130}}  \,  \begin{pmatrix}
0\\  -9\\ 7 
\end{pmatrix}\right) 
$$

Comment: I think this solution takes after circle-circle intersection which I have tried. It works for the particular points A, B given in the question however during iteration, position of B varies and one point is B(21.07, 15.15, 8.4) while A is (0, 0, 0). This results in Complex Number: CH =   0.0000 +34.1335i. Infact, This is my major problem even when I used Inverse trigonometry. Any further help please.

Comment: Which of the points A, B, C you ascribed cos(theta) and sin(theta) to?

Comment: The formula I have provided is the one you are looking for according to yor question. I don't know what circle-circle intersection you are referring to unless you mean that $C$ always lies on a circle determined by the intersection of two spheres-- one centered at $A$ of radios $b$ and the other centered at $B$ with radius $a$. The circle is parametrized by the angle $\theta$ in the formula I wrote.

Comment: Basically given $A$, $B$ and the lengths $a$ and $b$ you can express $C(\theta)$ as a function of $\theta$. You did not mention any iterations in your question and there is no info about the lengths $a$ and $b$. If you have tried some formula you should have included it in your question and not let us waste our time rederiving it for you. The reason why you get complex number for |CH| is because if you change $B$ you change $c=|AB|$ and the three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ do not satisfy the three necessary triangle inequalities that guarantee the existence of the triangle $ABC$!

Comment: Triangle $ABC$ exists if and only if $a<b+c, \,\, b<c+a, \,\, c<a+b$. You have to include these conditions in your algorithm or whatever you are doing.

Comment: So basically during your iterations the the two spheres centered at $A$ and $B$ change positions but their respective radii $b$ and $a$ stay the same and at some point the two spheres stop intersecting  (become disjoint) and their intersection circle disappears (becomes complex).

Comment: I am sorry for not giving details of what I have tried. I just wanted my current problem known and seek for help. Anyway please pardon that. Like I said, my goal is to determine a point in cartesian coordinate geometry (3D) given any two points AB. The point to be determined say Point C(x,y,z) is such that I can get to point B from A in just one bend instead of directly getting to point A from Point B.

Comment: What is θ in the equation you derived, is it from Point C and if yes, then I can apply Cosine Rule to derive it.

Comment: Parameter $\theta$ determines point $C$. You cannot find $\theta$ "by cosine rule" because $\theta$ is free. In other words, according to the way you have stated the problem, there is a whole circle of points $C$ that solves your problem. This means that the solution to your problem is not unique, but it is a set of points all lying on a circle which is parametrized by the parameter $\theta$.  You can simply fix $\theta$ anyway you want, and you can find one possible $C=(C_1,C_2,C_3)$ according to the formula I wrote. That's it. Nothing more can be done unless you include extra restrictions.

Comment: Sorry to disturb. I just want to be sure of my computations. When I took cross product of **(AB x e1)** I got **_(0, 9, -7)_** while **(AB x (AB x e1))** resulted in **_(-130, 28, 36)_**. These are different from what you posted in the example stated in your earlier explanation to my question. Please, do i have a mistake in my computation or you used different numbers?  I observed cross product as: **[a x b = (a2.b3-b2.a3, b1.a3-a1.b3, a1.b2-b1.a2)]**

Comment: No you do not have a mistake in your computations. And neither do I. I also normalize the vectors, i.e. I multiply them by on ever their length to obtain unit vectors. So my vector $(-65, 14, 18)$ is one half of  $(-130, 28, 36)$. So $AB\times (AB \times e_1) = (-130, 28, 36)$ but $$\frac{AB\times (AB \times e_1) }{|AB\times (AB \times e_1) |} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4749}}(-65, 14, 18).$$

Comment: Perfect way out!!!

Answer (score 0):

The known values of $|AC|$ and $|BC|$ essentially give you equations for the coordinates of $C$. For instance if we have $|AC|=d_1$ and $C$ is the point $(x,y,z)$ then,

$$|AC|=d_1 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2=d_1^2,$$

similarly,

$$|BC|=d_2 \Rightarrow (4-x)^2+(7-y)^2+(9-z)^2 = d_2^2.$$

These equations however are not enough to uniquely specify the ordered pair for $C$. They equations determine the shape of the triangle, but not its orientation. As such there will be a free variable which the other two will depend on.

I solved for $x,y,z$ in Maple for the specific case when $z=0$.

$$\color{blue}{x = {\frac {2}{65}}\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}+{\frac {292}{65}}-{\frac {2}{65}}\,{d_{
{2}}}^{2}}$$ $$\color{blue}{-{\frac {7}{130}}\,\sqrt {-{d_{{1}}}^{4}-32\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}-
21316+2\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}{d_{{2}}}^{2}+292\,{d_{{2}}}^{2}-{d_{{2}}}^{4}}}
$$

$$\color{red}{y={\frac {7}{130}}\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}+{\frac {511}{65}}-{\frac {7}{130}}\,{d
_{{2}}}^{2}}$$ $$\color{red}{+{\frac {2}{65}}\,\sqrt {-{d_{{1}}}^{4}-32\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}-
21316+2\,{d_{{1}}}^{2}{d_{{2}}}^{2}+292\,{d_{{2}}}^{2}-{d_{{2}}}^{4}}
} $$

$$z=0$$

---

If either of $d_1$ or $d_2$ are too short, then it shouldn't be possible to construct a triangle. This reveals itself through the expression inside the square roots; which is called the discriminant. If the discriminant is negative then it is not possible to form a triangle with the specified distances.

I plotted the discriminant in the specific cases when $d_1=4$ (first graph) and when $d_1=2$ (second graph). By observing the graphs you can see that only a certain range of $d_2$ values will result in a positive discriminant; too long or too short and there will not be a solution. Also note that the shorter I make $d_1$ the fewer possibilities there are.

- $d_1=4$
  [image: Graph of discriminant when d_1=4]
- $d_1=2$
  [image: Graph of discriminant when d_1=2]

Comment: how can I quantify the smallness you referred to as 'too small'. For instance at a point, |AC|=53.12, and |BC|=11 but I could not obtain the solution. Even on inverse trigonometry, it results in complex Number

Comment: The distances have to satisfy the triangle inequality. If the inequality, $|AC|+|BC|<|AB|$, is not satisfied then the triangle will be impossible to construct. For instance consider the example where the distance from $A$ to $B$ is 100 units long, but $|AC|=|BC|=2$; intuitively it should be obvious that the latter two lengths are too short, but you can verify this definitively using the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier to do it in two dimensions, so let's start with that - A(0,0) and B(0,$\sqrt 146$).  (|AB| = $\sqrt{146}$ follows from the coordinates you gave and the Pythagorean theorem.)  The law of cosines then will give you that the y coordinate of C is $$\frac{|AC|^2 - |BC|^2 + 146}{2\sqrt{146}}$$ and the Pythagorean theorem will give you the x coordinate as $$\sqrt{|AC|^2 - \frac{(|AC|^2 - |BC|^2 + 146)^2}{584}}$$  (If this is imaginary, no suitable point exists.)

From there it's relatively easy.  You'll want to put your x- and y-axes back into 3-dimensional space.  Of course, your y-axis will run from the origin to (4,7,9), so multiply each term by the y-coordinate and divide by $\sqrt{146}$.  To find an orthogonal vector, you use something called the dot product, which is equal to the product of the magnitudes divided by the cosine.  In Cartesian coordinates, you work out the dot product by multiplying each coordinate and then adding the products.  To get a right angle, you want it to be zero, so (21,6,-14) is appropriate.  Again multiply each term, this time by the x-coordinate, and divide by $\sqrt{673}$.  Add the two and you'll get an appropriate point.

Comment: Could you explain further a little. For instance, how did you obtain √146 in Point B. Also, why multiply x coordinate by 21, 6, and -14 and divide by √673.

Comment: The first number comes from the Pythagorean theorem.  (16 + 49 + 81 = 146.)

Answer (score 0):

Find the angle C and altitude CH ( H is on AB) by Sine Rule in the plane of ABC. All angles are known.

The locus of C is a circle whose plane is perpendicular to AB. Sides $ AC \rightarrow Ac $ and $ BC \rightarrow Bc $ are rotated generators of a *double cone* with cone base radius CH by means of a rotation  parameter $t$.

By using cross and dot vector products the variable unknown parameters can be found out in terms of $t$.

Comment: Given Points A(0,0,0) and B(21, 15, 8), can you explain better how your explanation works because I tried but only got complex Number using other methods