# Find 3D coordinates for third point of a triangle given the other two points and their angles

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

How can I deduced the third point that forms a triangle in 3D.  I have the cartesian location of two points say A, B and the lengths of the three sides.

I am mostly particular about the z-axis of this point because with trig functions, I have obtained perfect values for x,y axes. but the z-axis' value is a little bit erroneous.

Here is an image of the triangle:

[image: 3D View of a Triangle formed from Known two points]

Comment: The side lengths you've given don't form a triangle in the first place. Even if they did, there would not be a unique location for C because no information is given about the triangle's orientation in space.

Comment: AC seems to be way to large - did you have an error? C is an intersection of two spheres - means that C lies on circle which is the intersection of the two spheres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this question is a duplicate of your previous question "[How to determine $x, y, z$ coordinates of the third vertex of a 3D triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893667/how-to-determine-x-y-z-coordinates-of-the-third-vertex-of-a-3d-triangle)". Isn't it clearly settled? You can ask this question as much as you want, but the answer is not going to change. The problem may not have a solution (due to a violation of one of the three triangle inequalities) and if there is one, it is not going to be unique but a whole circle of points $C$ that satisfy your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the known points A and B are the endpoints of an axle, say from a bicycle wheel:

[image: wheel]

Think about the given lengths as the lengths of the spokes of the wheel.
Knowledge about the lengths $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ alone will not give a single solution for the position of point C. In fact, there are infinitely many solutions on the rim of the wheel. For a bicycle wheel $\overline{AC} = \overline{BC}$, but even if they are different, the analogy holds: just imagine the spokes on one side to be longer than on the other.

So when you say you are looking for a point, you are actually looking for a circle.